# How would I create a text file in Delphi

Tags: file, delphi, createfile

I have a program where users register for my program and a text file is created for them. 
I have tried using the CreateFile function but am not sure on the parameters. How would I create a textfile for each user as they register using this, or any other function?

Comment: You can use a `TFileStream`, or `WriteLn` in a console app, or `TStringList.SaveToFile` if the file isn't too large (under a few hundred megs). There are dozens of existing posts here about using all of those methods; do some searching and decide which works best for your particular requirements. There's usually no need to resort to low-level API code like `CreateFile` for simple text file output.

Comment: AFAIK, you can also use Writeln in a non-console app, if you write to a text file (and not to the console). But I would use TBufferedFileStream and a TTextWriter, or, like in Andreas' answer, a TStringList.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you can create a stringlist and save that to file:

```
procedure MakeAStringlistAndSaveThat;
var
  MyText: TStringlist;
begin
  MyText:= TStringlist.create;
  try
    MyText.Add('line 1');
    MyText.Add('line 2');
    MyText.SaveToFile('c:\folder\filename.txt');
  finally
    MyText.Free
  end; {try}
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to write two lines to a text file:

Using `TFile`:

```
fn := 'out.txt';

// method 1
TFile.WriteAllLines(fn, ['Line1','Line2']);

// method 2
TFile.WriteAllText(fn, 'Line1'+sLineBreak+'Line2');

// method 3
TFile.WriteAllText(fn, 'Line1');
TFile.AppendAllText(fn, sLineBreak);
TFile.AppendAllText(fn, 'Line2');
```

Using `TStringList`:

```
const fn := 'out.txt';
var sl := TStringList.Create;
try
  sl.Add('Line1');
  sl.Add('Line2');
  sl.SaveToFile(fn);
finally
  sl.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Shortest answer possible:

```
FileCreate('filename.txt');
```

`FileCreate` is declared in `System.SysUtils` and is actually a function returning a `THandle`. (The return value is simply discarded when you don't assign it upon calling.)
I'm just showing the above code for snappiness; most of the time it's not good programming practice to ignore the return value. Especially in this case where you definitely will need it further on.

The return value is `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` if the call was not successful, otherwise it holds the file handle of the newly created file. 
Even if you don't need to use the file right away, you'll need the handle: the file will not be accessible until the handle is released by calling the `FileClose` function. So, the *proper* shortest answer becomes

```
FileClose(FileCreate('filename.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Much Simpler Way To Create a File (For those who found this page years later like I did) is to simply use AssignFile('FileName.TXT'). It creates a fresh file that you can upload text to.

Example(My Gr10 Highschool Delphi Practical):

```
begin
  AssignFile(TFReceipt,'Receipt.TXT');
  redtEReceiptBod.Lines.SaveToFile('Receipt.TXT');
  Showmessage('Receipt generated');
end;
```

It Takes the content of any string and places it in the file.
To make the file readable (Remove the page break markers like /par) you can change the property of the Rich Edit (or any other string container) to
RichEdit.plaintext:=true;
This removes all the unnecessary page break content.

*Warning*
Keep in mind this was from my Highschool project so it is not very complex and might not work in all circumstances.