# How to append to text file in Delphi?

Tags: file, delphi, text

I am designing a program that writes to and stores data in a text file. The problem is that whenever I enter new data into the file, the old data is cleared and just that one entry (line) is there. I was originally saying Rewrite(tFile) every time but now use a boolean to check if the text file has been rewritten. I still get the same problem..

```
    begin
    AssignFile(tNotifications, 'Notifications.txt');
    if bRewritten = False then
      begin
        Rewrite(tNotifications);
        bRewritten := True;
      end;
     Writeln('test');
     CloseFile(tNotifications);
```

Comment: Better use `TStringList`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After `AssignFile()` you must make a choise, whether to **`Reset`** to read the file, or if you are going to write to the file, whether to **`Append`** to the file or **`Rewrite`** the file.

If you want to **retain existing data** in the file and just append additional data, then you call **`Append()`**.

If you want to **replace existing data** in the file with new data, then you call **`Rewrite`**.

I don't understand what the purpose of your boolean `bRewritten` is, I would expect you to set it somewhere else in your program as a signal for the file writing routine to either call `Append()` or `ReWrite()`.

---

In an [answer to an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51746514/2292722) it was suggested to use a `TStringList` and its `SaveToFile()` method. If you would use `TStringList` and you would want to append, you would first read the file (`StringList.ReadFromFile()`), add new strings to the StringList and finally save (`StringList.SaveToFile()`). To rewrite the existing file you would just omit the reading before adding strings to the StringList and saving.

I support using a `TStringList` as a modern and more convenient solution.

Comment: A `TStringList` is very easy to use, but I wouldn't recommend it for a log file that gets updated very often. It is slow (because the entire file needs to be rewritten when appending just a single line) and it causes unnecessary writes on a ssd drive.

Comment: @Sebastian, so you would recommend old Pascal I/O instead?

Comment: Old pascal I/O doesn't support Unicode, so I avoid that. I'd go with `TFile.WriteAllText` and `TFile.AppendAllText` (but be careful because of [Bug 13839](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13839)).

Comment: Now I should think how to emulate `TFile.WriteAllText` in Delphi 6 in order to append UTF-8 strings in SSD friendly way.

Answer (score 13):

Oldstyle [solution](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Append) (have you looked at `See Also` section in `AssignFile` help?):

```
AssignFile(tNotifications, 'Notifications.txt');
Append(tNotifications);
Writeln(tNotifications, newtext);
```

For fresh Delphi versions ([help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/IOUtils.TFile.AppendAllText)):

```
add IOUtils to uses
...
TFile.AppendAllText('Notifications.txt', newtext);
```

Comment: Note that `AppendAllText` does not include a line break, so if you want a line break, you'll have to add it yourself. Such as `TFile.AppendAllText('Notifications.txt', newtext+sLineBreak);`

Answer (score 0):

Or examine "append". Btw: AssignFile can be substituted by the more correct Assign.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the correctness of Assign. [See documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.AssignFile): "Note: To avoid scope conflicts, AssignFile replaces the Assign procedure that was available in early versions of the Delphi product. However, for backward compatibility, Assign is still available."